# What is the chance to find a pokemon at a spot with green leaves?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes there are these "rustling" green leaves on the map. It is believed that this is a spot, where pokemons may be located.

Is it known with what probability a pokemon can be found there?

Comment: I doubt the devs will tell us things like that.

Answer (score 4):

In a perfect gaming environment, 100%. That leaf thing is supposed to be a natural law.

However, in current server overload conditions, data isn't pushed often enough for the animation you're seeing to be connected to the dynamic movement of the Ps. Refresh often. Did you just see the server gear load? If so, and you still see rustling, it's going to be within about 25 meters at the outside most of the rustle, usually more like 10. If you're on top of it and no pop, reload. Fastest way to get a server push us to deliberately lose signal by letting the phone sleep and then wake it up. The top of the screen will say the data connection was lost and it will refresh and serve you the most recent data for your loc. Or relaunch the app.

Stale data is a problem atm.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: Empirical experience. Try it yourself for verification. A large playing field area is the best place to get tracking sorted out (grass, orientation signal from panel on spin of unlocked compass with individual P selected, etc. etc.) - my town has a large complex of connected soccer and baseball fields, so you really can correlate LoS out there. So open and flat. Very popular spot. Funny to watch people swarm it.